# Bounded meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I just want to make a clarification with regard to bounded meromorphic functions on the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. Would they be constant?

Here's what I do know:
$(1)$ Liouville's Theorem states that a bounded $\textit{entire}$ function (holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$) is constant.
$(2)$ Holomorphic functions on all of the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty \}$ are constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes: if a meromorphic function is bounded, it is in particular bounded near its singularities. This means that the singularities are [removable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity), so the function extends to a bounded holomorphic function on all of $\mathbb C$.