# Is $\sin(z^3)$ bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know $\sin x$ is bounded function if $x$ is real. but what about if $x$ is a complex number? moreover, what about $\sin(z^3)$, where $z$ is a complex number? I tried this by Taylor's series but was not successful.

Comment: A complex analytic function is bounded if and only if it is a constant function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\sin z$ and $z^3$ are analytic, $\sin z^3$ is also analytic. By [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)), a bounded function analytic on the whole $\mathbb{C}$ is constant. Since $\sin z^3$ is not constant, it is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you....what about if function is not analytic e.g $\frac{sin(z)}{cos(z)+1}$

Comment: @ArunSharma For this specific case, note that $\cos z$ can be arbitrarily close to $-1$, so the denominator can be made arbitrarily small, and the whole function is unbounded. In general, Liouville's theorem holds for meromorphic functions, too (and your function is meromorphic): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901490/bounded-meromorphic-function-on-mathbbc

Comment: @ArunSharma: it is even worse: such a function has a simple pole at $z=\pi$.

Comment: @ArunSharma: The zeros of $\cos(z) + 1$, namely $z = (2k + 1)\pi$ for integer $k$, are also zeros of $\sin z$, so $g(z) = \frac{\sin z}{\cos z + 1}$ has an analytic extension by the Riemann extension theorem, and may therefore be regarded as a non-constant entire function. (If that happened not to be the case, the function would instead have isolated singularities in the complex plane, and not even be locally bounded.)

Comment: @lisyarus So, what about $\frac{1}{8z^{16} + 4z^8 + 2z^2 +1}$. is this function bounded ? I think it is also not bounded by the same reasoning (Liouville's theorem)

Comment: @lisyarus what about $e^{i \mid z \mid }$

Comment: @ArunSharma $\frac{1}{p(x)}$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial, has poles since $p(x)$ has roots but the fundamental theorem of algebra, hence unbounded. $e^{i|z|}$ takes it's values on the unit circle, and clearly *is* bounded.

Comment: @lisyarus Oh yes, you are right, p(x) can have roots. I forgot, we are working in C. Thanks.....a lot

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Actually, since $\sin z \approx z$ and $\cos z \approx 1 - \frac{z^2}{2}$, the whole fraction will be $\approx \frac{1}{z}$, without analytic extension.

Comment: @lisyarus but my z varies over C so, why $e^{i\mid z \mid }$ is bounded?

Comment: @ArunSharma $z \in \mathbb{C}$, but $|z| \in \mathbb{R}$, so $i |z|$ is pure imaginary, so by Euler's formula $|e^{i|z|}| = 1$.

Comment: @lisyarus: Whoops...right you are. Apparently I'm not fully awake yet.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Me too - didn't notice $\sin z$ and $\cos z + 1$ share roots, so it is not as simple as I've said in the earlier comment. Thank you for noticing that!